# Bidirectional Edmonds-Karp algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

The Edmonds-Karp algorithm relies on breadth-first search in order to find an augmenting path in the residual flow network. This version of the algorithm uses bidirectional breadth-first search in order to speed up the entire algorithm. My profiling reports consistently speed ups of at least 3.

The files **DirectedGraphNode.java**, **EdgeWeightFunction.java**, **AbstractMaximumFlowFinder.java** and **EdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder.java** may be found at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79233/edmonds-karp-algorithm-for-maximum-flow-in-java

The new and modified files are:

**BidirectionalEdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.model.flow.support;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.DirectedGraphNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.EdgeWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.flow.AbstractMaximumFlowFinder;

public class BidirectionalEdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder 
extends AbstractMaximumFlowFinder {

    private final Queue<DirectedGraphNode> queueA;
    private final Queue<DirectedGraphNode> queueB;
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, DirectedGraphNode> parentMapA;
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, DirectedGraphNode> parentMapB;
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Integer> distanceMapA;
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Integer> distanceMapB;

    public BidirectionalEdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder() {
        this.queueA = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.queueB = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.parentMapA = new HashMap<>();
        this.parentMapB = new HashMap<>();
        this.distanceMapA = new HashMap<>();
        this.distanceMapB = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public FlowData findMaximumFlow(final DirectedGraphNode source, 
                                    final DirectedGraphNode sink, 
                                    final EdgeWeightFunction capacityFunction) {
        if (source.equals(sink)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The source node is the same as the sink node.");
        }

        // Proceed to the actual computation.
        double flow = 0.0;
        final EdgeWeightFunction f = new EdgeWeightFunction();
        final EdgeWeightFunction c = capacityFunction; // Just rename.
        final List<DirectedGraphNode> graph = 
                getConnectedComponent(source, sink);

        if (graph == null) {
            // Sink not reachable from source.
            return new FlowData(f, 0.0);
        }

        List<DirectedGraphNode> path = null;

        while ((path = findAugmentingPath(source, sink, f, c)).size() > 1) {
            flow += findMinimumEdgeAndRemove(path, f, c);
        }

        return new FlowData(f, flow);
    }

    /**
     * Finds a (shortest in terms of edge amount) path of which each edge has
     * nonnegative residual weight.
     * 
     * @param source the source node.
     * @param sink   the sink node.
     * @param c      the capacity function.
     * @param f      the flow function.
     * 
     * @return       a list of nodes of a path or <code>null</code> if there is
     *               no path anymore.
     */
    private List<DirectedGraphNode> 
        findAugmentingPath(final DirectedGraphNode source,
                           final DirectedGraphNode sink,
                           final EdgeWeightFunction f,
                           final EdgeWeightFunction c) {
        queueA.clear();
        queueB.clear();
        parentMapA.clear();
        parentMapB.clear();
        distanceMapA.clear();
        distanceMapB.clear();

        queueA.add(source);
        queueB.add(sink);
        parentMapA.put(source, null);
        parentMapB.put(sink, null);
        distanceMapA.put(source, 0);
        distanceMapB.put(sink, 0);

        DirectedGraphNode touchNode = null;
        int bestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        while (queueA.size() > 0 && queueB.size() > 0) {
            if (touchNode != null 
                    && distanceMapA.get(queueA.peek()) +
                       distanceMapB.get(queueB.peek()) >= bestDistance) {
                return tracebackPath(touchNode, parentMapA, parentMapB);
            }

            DirectedGraphNode current = queueA.remove();

            if (parentMapB.containsKey(current)
                    && bestDistance > distanceMapA.get(current) + 
                                      distanceMapB.get(current)) {
                bestDistance = distanceMapA.get(current) + 
                               distanceMapB.get(current);
                touchNode = current;
            }

            for (final DirectedGraphNode neighbor : current.all()) {
                if (parentMapA.containsKey(neighbor)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (residualEdgeWeight(current, neighbor, f, c) > 0) {
                    parentMapA.put(neighbor, current);
                    distanceMapA.put(neighbor, distanceMapA.get(current) + 1);
                    queueA.add(neighbor);
                }
            }

            current = queueB.remove();

            if (parentMapA.containsKey(current)
                    && bestDistance > distanceMapA.get(current) + 
                                      distanceMapB.get(current)) {
                bestDistance = distanceMapA.get(current) + 
                               distanceMapB.get(current);
                touchNode = current;
            }

            for (final DirectedGraphNode neighbor : current.all()) {
                if (parentMapB.containsKey(neighbor)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (residualEdgeWeight(neighbor, current, f, c) > 0) {
                    parentMapB.put(neighbor, current);
                    distanceMapB.put(neighbor, distanceMapB.get(current) + 1);
                    queueB.add(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }

        return Collections.<DirectedGraphNode>emptyList();
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.DirectedGraphNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.EdgeWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.flow.AbstractMaximumFlowFinder.FlowData;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.flow.support.BidirectionalEdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.model.flow.support.EdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder;

public class Demo {

    private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 25;
    private static final int SIZE = 2000;
    private static final float EDGE_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.03f;

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        smallDemo();
        largeDemo(rnd);
    }

    // This sample graph is from Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition,
    // page 727.
    public static void smallDemo() {
        final List<DirectedGraphNode> network = new ArrayList<>(7);

        final DirectedGraphNode s = new DirectedGraphNode("s");
        final DirectedGraphNode v1 = new DirectedGraphNode("v1");
        final DirectedGraphNode v2 = new DirectedGraphNode("v2");
        final DirectedGraphNode v3 = new DirectedGraphNode("v3");
        final DirectedGraphNode v4 = new DirectedGraphNode("v4");
        final DirectedGraphNode t = new DirectedGraphNode("t");

        s.connectTo(v1);
        s.connectTo(v2);

        v1.connectTo(v3);

        v2.connectTo(v1);
        v2.connectTo(v4);

        v3.connectTo(v2);
        v3.connectTo(t);

        v4.connectTo(v3);
        v4.connectTo(t);

        v3.connectTo(v3);
        v4.connectTo(v4);
        v2.connectTo(v2);

        final EdgeWeightFunction capacities = new EdgeWeightFunction();

        capacities.put(s, v1, 16);
        capacities.put(s, v2, 13);
        capacities.put(v1, v3, 12);
        capacities.put(v2, v1, 4);
        capacities.put(v2, v4, 14);
        capacities.put(v3, v2, 9);
        capacities.put(v3, t, 20);
        capacities.put(v4, v3, 7);
        capacities.put(v4, t, 4);

        final FlowData fd = 
                new EdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder()
                .findMaximumFlow(s, t, capacities);

        System.out.println("Total flow: " + fd.flowValue);

        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(s,  v1, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(s,  v2, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v1, v3, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v2, v1, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v2, v4, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v3, v2, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v3, t,  0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v4, v3, 0));
        System.out.println(fd.flowFunction.getOrDefault(v4, t,  0));
    }

    public static void largeDemo(final Random rnd) {
        final FlowNetwork flowNetwork = createRandomNetwork(SIZE,
                                                             EDGE_LOAD_FACTOR,
                                                             rnd);

        final DirectedGraphNode source = choose(flowNetwork.network, rnd);
        final DirectedGraphNode sink =   choose(flowNetwork.network, rnd);

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final FlowData flowData1 = new EdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder()
                .findMaximumFlow(source, sink, flowNetwork.capacityFunction);
        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time: " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");
        System.out.println("Flow: " + flowData1.flowValue);

        final boolean sourceCorrect = verifySource(source, 
                                                   flowData1.flowFunction,
                                                   flowData1.flowValue);

        final boolean sinkCorrect = verifySink(sink, 
                                               flowData1.flowFunction,
                                               flowData1.flowValue);

        System.out.println("Source check: " + sourceCorrect);
        System.out.println("Sink check:   " + sinkCorrect);
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.println();

        // Bidirectional Edmonds-Karp.
        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final FlowData flowData2 = 
                new BidirectionalEdmondsKarpMaximumFlowFinder()
                .findMaximumFlow(source, sink, flowNetwork.capacityFunction);
        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time: " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");
        System.out.println("Flow: " + flowData2.flowValue);

        final boolean sourceCorrect2 = verifySource(source, 
                                                    flowData2.flowFunction,
                                                    flowData2.flowValue);

        final boolean sinkCorrect2 = verifySink(sink, 
                                                flowData2.flowFunction,
                                                flowData2.flowValue);

        System.out.println("Source check: " + sourceCorrect2);
        System.out.println("Sink check:   " + sinkCorrect2);
    }

    public static class FlowNetwork {
        public final List<DirectedGraphNode> network;
        public final EdgeWeightFunction capacityFunction;

        public FlowNetwork(final List<DirectedGraphNode> network,
                           final EdgeWeightFunction capacityFunction) {
            this.network = network;
            this.capacityFunction = capacityFunction;
        }
    }

    public static FlowNetwork createRandomNetwork(final int size,
                                                   final float edgeLoadFactor,
                                                   final Random rnd) {
        final List<DirectedGraphNode> network = new ArrayList<>(size);
        final EdgeWeightFunction capacityFunction = new EdgeWeightFunction();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            network.add(new DirectedGraphNode("" + i));
        }

        int edges = (int)(Math.min(0.95f, edgeLoadFactor) * size * size);

        while (edges > 0) {
            final DirectedGraphNode tail = choose(network, rnd);
            final DirectedGraphNode head = choose(network, rnd);
            tail.connectTo(head);
            capacityFunction.put(tail, head, rnd.nextInt(MAX_CAPACITY));
            --edges;
        }

        return new FlowNetwork(network, capacityFunction);
    }

    private static <E> E choose(final List<E> list, final Random rnd) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return list.get(rnd.nextInt(list.size()));
    }

    private static boolean verifySource(final DirectedGraphNode source,
                                        final EdgeWeightFunction f,
                                        final double actualMaximumFlow) {
        double flow = 0.0;

        for (final DirectedGraphNode child : source) {
            flow += f.getOrDefault(source, child, 0);
        }

        for (final DirectedGraphNode parent : source.parents()) {
            flow -= f.getOrDefault(parent, source, 0);
        }

        return flow == actualMaximumFlow;
    }

    private static boolean verifySink(final DirectedGraphNode sink,
                                      final EdgeWeightFunction f,
                                      final double actualMaximumFlow) {
        double flow = 0.0;

        for (final DirectedGraphNode child : sink) {
            flow -= f.getOrDefault(sink, child, 0);
        }

        for (final DirectedGraphNode parent : sink.parents()) {
            flow += f.getOrDefault(parent, sink, 0);
        }

        return flow == actualMaximumFlow;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is being discussed on meta: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/process-to-follow-when-un-answered-questions-have-a-follow-on